# ConfigureAwait(false) on Top Level Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to figure out if ConfigureAwait(false) should be used on top level requests. Reading this post from a somewhat authority of the subject:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

...he recommends something like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> MyControllerAction(...)
{
    try
    {
        var report = await _adapter.GetReportAsync();
        return Json(report, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json("myerror", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  // really slow without configure await
    }
}

public async Task<TodaysActivityRawSummary> GetReportAsync()
{           
    var data = await GetData().ConfigureAwait(false);

    return data
}
```

**...it says to using ConfigureAwait(false) on every await *except* the top level call.** *However when doing this my exception takes several seconds to return to the caller* vs. using it and it and having it come back right away.

What is the best practice for MVC controller actions that call async methods? Should I use ConfigureAwait in the controller itself or just in the service calls that use awaits to request data, etc.? If I don't use it on the top level call, waiting several seconds for the exception seems problematic. I don't need the HttpContext and I've seen other posts that said always use ConfigureAwait(false) if you don't need the context.

**Update:**
I was missing ConfigureAwait(false) somewhere in my chain of calls which was causing the exception to not be returned right away. However the question still remains as posted as to whether or not ConfigureAwait(false) should be used at the top level.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example that shows the timing difference?

Comment: @Stepen Cleary I realized I was missing ConfiguredAwait somewhere in my chain. Sorry for the confusion.Now the exception comes back right away. I'm still trying to figure out why it should be ommited from the top level though. Maybe I missed it, but I don't think the blog really explains that.

Comment: @StephenCleary it's also not clear what you do if you have only ONE await and not a chain of them.. if you still use ConfigureAwait(false) at the top level.... For instance pushing something off to a service bus. In this case you are calling a third party api and this is you only visible await in the chain.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Is it a high traffic website? One possible explanation might be that you're experiencing `ThreadPool`starvation when you are *not* using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Without `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the `await` continuation is queued via `AspNetSynchronizationContext.Post`, which implementation boils down to [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/SynchronizationHelper.cs,f0184c54fac66559,references):

```
Task newTask = _lastScheduledTask.ContinueWith(_ => SafeWrapCallback(action));
_lastScheduledTask = newTask; // the newly-created task is now the last one
```

Here, `ContinueWith` is used *without* `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` (I'd speculate, to make continuations truly asynchronous and reduce a chance for low stack conditions). Thus, it acquires a vacant thread from `ThreadPool` to execute the continuation on. In theory, it might happen to be the same thread where the antecedent task for `await` has finished, but most likely it'd be a different thread.

At this point, if ASP.NET thread pool is starving (or has to grow to accommodate a new thread request), you might be experiencing a delay. It's worth mentioned that the thread pool consists of two sub-pools: IOCP threads and worker threads (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23262585/1768303) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22475242/1768303) for some extra details). Your `GetReportAsync` operations is likely to complete on an IOCP thread sub-pool, which doesn't seem to be starving. OTOH, the `ContinueWith` continuation runs on a worker thread  sub-pool, which appears to be starving in your case.

This is not going to happen in case `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used all the way through. In that case, all `await` continuations will run synchronously on the same threads the corresponding antecedent tasks have ended, be it either IOCP or worker threads.

You can compare the thread usage for both scenarios, with and without `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I'd expect this number to be larger when `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't used:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log("Total number of threads in use={0}",
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
    return Json("myerror", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  // really slow without configure await
}
```

You can also try increasing the size of the ASP.NET thread pool (for diagnostics purpose, rather than an ultimate solution), to see if the described scenario is indeed the case here:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <applicationPool 
        maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="6000"
        maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" 
        requestQueueLimit="6000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

**Updated** to address the comments:

> I realized I was missing a ContinueAwait somewhere in my chain. Now it
>   works fine when throwing an exception even when the top level doesn't
>   use ConfigureAwait(false).

This suggests that your code or a 3rd party library in use might be using blocking constructs (`Task.Result`, `Task.Wait`, `WaitHandle.WaitOne`, perhaps with some added timeout logic). Have you looked for those? Try the `Task.Run` suggestion from the bottom of this update. Besides, I'd still do the thread count diagnostics to rule out thread pool starvation/stuttering.

> So are you saying that if I DO use ContinueAwait even at the top level
>   I lose the whole benefit of the async?

No, I'm not saying that. The whole point of `async` is to avoid blocking threads while waiting for something, and that goal is achieved regardless of the added value of `ContinueAwait(false)`.

What I'm saying is that *not using* `ConfigureAwait(false)` might introduce redundant context switching (what usually means thread switching), which might be a problem in ASP.NET if thread pool is working at its capacity. Nevertheless, a redundant thread switch is still better than a blocked thread, in terms of the server scalability.

In all fairness, [*using* `ContinueAwait(false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28410046/1768303) might also cause redundant context switching, especially if it's used inconsistently across the chain of calls.

That said, `ContinueAwait(false)` is also often misused as a remedy against deadlocks caused by [blocking on asynchronous code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). That's why I suggested above to look for those blocking construct across all code base.

> However the question still remains as posted as to whether or not
>   ConfigureAwait(false) should be used at the top level.

I hope Stephen Cleary could elaborate better on this, by here's my thoughts.

There's always some "super-top level" code that invokes your top-level code. E.g., in case of a UI app, it's the framework code which invokes an `async void` event handler. In case of ASP.NET, it's the asynchronous controller's `BeginExecute`. It is *the responsibility of that super-top level code* to make sure that, once your async task has completed, the continuations (if any) run on the correct synchronization context. It is *not* the responsibility of the code of your task. E.g., there might be no continuations at all, like with a fire-and-forget `async void` event handler; why would you care to restore the context inside such handler?

Thus, inside your top-level methods, if you don't care about the context for `await` continuations, do use `ConfigureAwait(false)` as soon as you can.

Moreover, if you're using a 3rd party library which is known to be context agnostic but still might be using `ConfigureAwait(false)` inconsistently, you may want to wrap the call with `Task.Run` or something like [`WithNoContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28410046/1768303). You'd do that to get the chain of the async calls off the context, in advance:

```
var report = await Task.Run(() =>
    _adapter.GetReportAsync()).ConfigureAwait(false);
return Json(report, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This would introduce one extra thread switch, but might save you a lot more of those if `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used inconsistently inside `GetReportAsync` or any of its child calls. It'd also serve as a workaround for potential deadlocks caused by those blocking constructs inside the call chain (if any).

Note however, in ASP.NET `HttpContext.Current` is not the only static property which is flowed with `AspNetSynchronizationContext`. E.g., there's also `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. Make sure you really don't care about loosing the context.

**Updated** to address the comment:

> For brownie points, maybe you can explain the effects of
>   ConfigureAwait(false)... What context isn't preserved.. Is it just the
>   HttpContext or the local variables of the class object, etc.?

All local variables of an `async` method are preserved across `await`, as well as the implicit `this` reference - by design. They actually gets captured into a compiler-generated async state machine structure, so technically they don't reside on the current thread's stack. In a way, it's similar to how a C# delegate captures local variables. In fact, an `await` continuation callback is itself a delegate passed to `ICriticalNotifyCompletion.UnsafeOnCompleted` (implemented by the object being awaited; for `Task`, it's [`TaskAwaiter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx); with `ConfigureAwait`, it's [`ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.configuredtaskawaitable(v=vs.110).aspx)).

OTOH, most of the **global state** (static/TLS variables, static class properties) is **not** automatically flowed across awaits. What does get flowed depends on a particular synchronization context. In the absence of one (or when `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used), the only global state preserved with  is what gets flowed by `ExecutionContext`. Microsoft's Stephen Toub has a great post on that: ["ExecutionContext vs SynchronizationContext"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx). He mentions `SecurityContext` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, which is crucial for security. Other than that, I'm not aware of any officially documented and complete list of global state properties flowed by `ExecutionContext`.

You could peek into [`ExecutionContext.Capture` source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs,3a777fa35a9f1ffe) to learn more about what exactly gets flowed, but you shouldn't depend on this specific implementation. Instead, you can always create your own global state flow logic, using something like Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncLocal`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) (or .NET 4.6 [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Or, to take it to the extreme, you could also ditch `ContinueAwait` altogether and create a custom awaiter, e.g. like this [`ContinueOnScope`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284998/pattern-for-calling-wcf-service-using-async-await). That would allow to have precise control over what thread/context to continue on and what state to flow.

Comment: As to this: *I'm still not clear why Stephen says not to use it at the top level.*  I think this is because on the top level you usually do something with the data/results you've obtained asynchronously. E.g., you'd update the UI and you'd want this to happen on the UI thread with the proper context. Apparently, this is not the case with your MVC controller method. @StephenCleary may want to jump in here and correct me.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites, glad it helped. One thing I forgot, check if you have `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />` in your `web.config`. It should be there by default, but worth checking.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I did some research after noticing this setting was missing and it looks like this is turned on by default in .net 4.5 per StephenCleary http://firstbestanswer.com/question/2drgnv/aspnet-vs-mvc-vs-webapi-usetaskfriendlysynchronizationcontext.html

Answer (score 24):

> However the question still remains as posted as to whether or not ConfigureAwait(false) should be used at the top level.

The rule of thumb for `ConfigureAwait(false)` is to use it whenever the rest of your method doesn't need the context.

In ASP.NET, the "context" is not actually well-defined anywhere. It does include things like `HttpContext.Current`, user principal, and user culture.

So, the question really comes down to: "Does `Controller.Json` require the ASP.NET context?" It's certainly possible that `Json` doesn't care about the context (since it can write the current response from its own controller members), but OTOH it does do "formatting", which may require the user culture to be resumed.

I don't know whether `Json` requires the context, but it's not documented one way or the other, and in general I assume that any calls into ASP.NET code may depend on the context. So I would *not* use `ConfigureAwait(false)` at the top-level in my controller code, just to be on the safe side.